# Webframework written in / compiling to SQL?

Tags: sql, frameworks

Many of the tasks in many web applications consist of checking and updating the state in a (typically relational) database. Often this logic is not more complex than the SQL statements needed to get and update the data. It seems to me that much of the logic should be  processable in SQL and that avoiding trips between the web app and the database would save a lot of time.

Is there a (preferably open source) web application framework that is written in SQL or compiles to SQL?

Comment: hell yeah, security who the f*** needs it!

Comment: @MrSimpleMind I don't understand how your comment relates to my question.

Comment: You want to run a solution/service directly thru web <-> db server ? or am I  getting it wrong ? no web application server logic inbetween (like no java, php, .net etc)

Comment: @MrSimpleMind Its not necessary to expose the db server directly, a (small and generic) wrapper would be ok. But the main app logic should live on the db server. Of course you must still not trust arbitrary input, but I don't think that this is conceptually impossible in this setup.

Comment: Okey, and what about parallelism, threading, security, configuration, performance measurments, logs, traceability, transaction mgmnt, etc... ? Sure, if it is an internal application and only a simple db model for put and get. But I mean if you deal with business logic .... real business logic :)

Comment: Well, that's in part why I am curious if such a thing exists. I don't think any of these are definitely impossible to achieve (I might be wrong of course). My premise is that much of what web applications typically do should be possible with SQL. So why not?

Comment: How much power will you get from the standardization community, how easy will it be to move from one database server to another? any cost aspects?

Comment: If it is possible it must be done! There are [webframeworks written in COBOL](http://www.coboloncogs.org/INDEX.HTM)!

Comment: Hi, Try this opensource project to create web gui (CRUD) 
to any datasource which support crud operations: 
https://github.com/vku1/sqlweb
Main language is SQL, really.